# Bootstrap datetime picker disable hours

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I am using [Bootsrap 3 Datetime Picker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#endisableddates). I find the documentation doesn't say much about how to disable/enable hours, all it says is this:

> disabledHours
>
> Default: false

Does someone now how to declare a disabled hour? which format?. I need to disable different hours for weekdays and for weekends.

Comment: It says here : http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#endisabledhours, that hours can be disabled using the option(for example) : `disabledHours: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]`

Comment: @stark Thanks! do we agree that info should be written in the `options` section rather than in the `functions` section? Anyway... do you know how can I enable different hours for weekdays and weekends?

Comment: In your question you suggest that you want to set different hours for weekends/weekdays.  The documentation says "Will allow or disallow hour selections (much like `disabledTimeIntervals`) but will affect **all days**" (emphasis added).  I don't think it will be possible to specify separate hours for separate days.

Comment: @EricDauenhauer no possible workaround using events and functions? ... :/ thnx for the answer anyway.

Comment: I'm not saying there is no possible workaround - I've never actually used this library.  But I don't think its an option that can be specified by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use some workaround using Ajax :

HTML :

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker">
      <span>Pick up a delivery time :</span>
      <input id="datepicker" data-format="DD/MM/YYYY - H:mm" name="delivery_time" type="text" class="form-control input-small">
    </div>
</div>
```

JS :

```
$('#datepicker').on('dp.change', function(e) {
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'theday='+JSON.stringify(e.date._d),
        url: 'ajax/disable_hours.php',
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.return == true) {
                $('#datepicker').data('DateTimePicker').enabledHours(
                    data.allowed_hours
                );
            } else {
                console.log(data);
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
```

PHP :

```
// GET PICKED WEEKDAY FROM JS
$theday = $_POST['theday']; // Get value of last picked date (js: .e.date._d)
$theday = substr($theday, 1,10); // Isolate yyyy-mm-dd
$theday = strtotime($theday); // Make it timeStamp
$theday = getDate($theday); // Create date info array

// SET OPENING HOURS
$allowed_times = array(
    'MondayOpen'      => 8,
    'MondayClose'     => 18,
    'TuesdayOpen'     => 8,
    'TuesdayClose'    => 18,
    'WednesdayOpen'   => 10,
    'WednesdayClose'  => 16,
    'ThursdayOpen'    => 8,
    'ThursdayClose'   => 18,
    'FridayOpen'      => 8,
    'FridayClose'     => 18,
    'SaturdayOpen'    => 9,
    'SaturdayClose'   => 12,
    'SundayOpen'      => 9,
    'SundayClose'     => 12
);

// USEFUL VARIABLES
$allowHours = array();

// SET THE ENABLED HOURS ARRAYS
switch ($theday['wday']) {

    // SUNDAY
    case 0:
        $open = $allowed_times['SundayOpen'];
        $close = $allowed_times['SundayClose'];

        $allowHours = array();
        for ($i = $open; $i < $close; $i++) {
            array_push($allowHours, $i);
        }

        die(json_encode(array("return" => true, "allowed_hours" => $allowHours)));

    // MONDAY
    case 1:
        $open = $allowed_times['MondayOpen'];
        $close = $allowed_times['MondayClose'];

        $allowHours = array();
        for ($i = $open; $i < $close; $i++) {
            array_push($allowHours, $i);
        }

        die(json_encode(array("return" => true, "allowed_hours" => $allowHours)));

    // TUESDAY
    case 2:
        $open = $allowed_times['TuesdayOpen'];
        $close = $allowed_times['TuesdayClose'];

        $allowHours = array();
        for ($i = $open; $i < $close; $i++) {
            array_push($allowHours, $i);
        }

        die(json_encode(array("return" => true, "allowed_hours" => $allowHours)));

    // WEDNESDAY
    case 3:
        $open = $allowed_times['WednesdayOpen'];
        $close = $allowed_times['WednesdayClose'];

        $allowHours = array();
        for ($i = $open; $i < $close; $i++) {
            array_push($allowHours, $i);
        }

        die(json_encode(array("return" => true, "allowed_hours" => $allowHours)));

    // THURSDAY
    case 4:
        $open = $allowed_times['ThursdayOpen'];
        $close = $allowed_times['ThursdayClose'];

        $allowHours = array();
        for ($i = $open; $i < $close; $i++) {
            array_push($allowHours, $i);
        }

        die(json_encode(array("return" => true, "allowed_hours" => $allowHours)));

    // FRIDAY
    case 5:
        $open = $allowed_times['FridayOpen'];
        $close = $allowed_times['FridayClose'];

        $allowHours = array();
        for ($i = $open; $i < $close; $i++) {
            array_push($allowHours, $i);
        }

        die(json_encode(array("return" => true, "allowed_hours" => $allowHours)));

    // SATURDAY
    case 6:
        $open = $allowed_times['SaturdayOpen'];
        $close = $allowed_times['SaturdayClose'];

        $allowHours = array();
        for ($i = $open; $i < $close; $i++) {
            array_push($allowHours, $i);
        }

        die(json_encode(array("return" => true, "allowed_hours" => $allowHours)));
}
```

There is certainly better out there but maybe it will help some.